# How to delete openmaptiles (OSM Mbtiles) layers

Tags: openstreetmap, sqlite, mbtiles, openmaptiles

I am struggling with converting PBF to Postgresql Table (importing only certain layers) or editing them, for the volume of the data. (world scale of PBF is about 80Gbs)

meanwhile, I have found that openmaptiles offers a very light mbtiles format of OSM data, though it is only up to zoom level 14

https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/tileset/osm/

From there mbtiles, I wanted to remove certain layers such as ocean polygons and other water boundaries (and maybe a few more as I wish).

I know mbtiles is a type of sqlite but I have realized that sqlite (mbtiles) viewer is not like QGIS layer like.

Will there be any GUI tools that I can handle mbtiles?

Comment: Did you try this QGIS plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/vector_tiles_reader/ ?